# Set text color by script in vim

Tags: vim

I am writing a small vim plugin, where I want to dynamically change the text color of a text in a specific buffer, by row and column.

Using a syntax highlighting expression did not work, since the text only consists of either ' ' or '='.

Example:

```
== ===== ==
==== ===
===
=======
==
========= =
```

I want *some* of them in green, some in red, some in white. If possible also change the background color for highlighting. Colors are dynamically defined by script.

I found something like this:

```
vim.command("match WarningMsg /*/".format(10, 4, 4 - 1))
```

That seems to turn some part of the buffer red. Though I have no idea why and how format() works...

Went through the vim documentation, but found no command like '`set_fg_col(color, row,col, w, h)`'

Is this possible at all?

Is there a way to work around it? Maybe using shell color escapes that are not displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for highlighting a particular buffer, *syntax highlighting* is the correct mechanism, as it is tied (via the *filetype* and the buffer-local `'syntax'` option) to a buffer.

`:match`, by contrast, applies to a *window*, so you'd have to use elaborate `:autocmd`s to make the scoping right. As both are powered by regular expressions and are therefore equivalent (well, syntax highlighting is more powerful, because groups can be contained and followed), choose syntax highlighting.

#### The syntax

With your particular syntax, you need to (statically) match on columns and lines indeed, as the symbols don't provide much distinction. Fortunately, Vim has special atoms like `\%l` and `\%c` that match in particular lines / columns. With those, you can build matches for text ranges. For example, to match (ASCII) characters 2-4 in line 3: `/\%3l\%>1c.*\%<5c/`. Use `:help /\%l` to learn more.

You could update the highlighting on demand via a custom command, or triggered via certain `:autocmd` events. (But you have to find a compromise between displaying out-of-sync stuff and performance; Vim wasn't made for this.)